# What will happen if fgetc reads 0xFF?

Tags: c, casting, fgetc

`fgetc` reads a character from a file at a time, and returns the character as type of `int`. If the file ends, then `fgetc` returns `EOF` ("probably" `(int)(-1)`). However, I have seen this so frequently:

```
char ch;

while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)  {  /* Do something. */  }
       |<--  PARN  -->|
```

This is what I concern:

1. `fgetc` reads `OxFF` and returns `0x000000FF`.
2. `0xFF` is assigned to `ch`. (type casting from `int` to `char`)
3. If `PARN` is type of `char`, then it will be promoted to `0xFFFFFFFF`.
4. Break out of the while loop because `PARN == EOF`. (stop reading from the file)

How can we tell reading `OxFF` and returning `EOF` apart?

Comment: This is the reason you declare `ch` to be of type `int` instead of `char`.

Comment: Then your code blows up.

Comment: Mostly, people declare `ch` as `char`.

Comment: @KevinDong: Well that's wrong. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole reason the return type of `fgetc` is `int` is because it can return either a value of an `unsigned char`, or `EOF`. This is clearly documented in the specification and in any good resource on learning C. If you use an object of type `char` to store the result, this is programmer error.

Comment: I got it. When I saw such code in other [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213308/file-pointers-behave-differently-when-passed-to-functions-why), I thought that it is wrong, so I ask here and check whether it is correct or not. Thanks a lot. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your concern is correct that the value gets typecast to char before the comparison is made.

The easiest solution is:

```
int chread;
while ((chread = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { char ch = chread; /* Do something. */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` returns the obtained character on success or `EOF` on failure.

If the failure has been caused by end-of-file condition, additionally sets the `eof` indicator (see [feof()](http://devdocs.io/c/io/feof)) on stream. If the failure has been caused by some other error, sets the error indicator (see[ferror()](http://devdocs.io/c/io/ferror) ) on stream.